# lib files are not loading (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, autoload

I am having trouble loading modules from the lib folders of my application. Here is the the file/module that i am trying to load:

[image]

```
# app/lib/reusable.rb    
module Reusable

  # Check if the value is completely blank & empty
  def is_empty(value)
  end

end
```

I have tried putting `#config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"` or
`Dir[Rails.root.join('lib/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }` inside  config/application.rb , but still it is not working.

I also have tried `config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"` and also tried moving all the file of /lib into app/lib like suggested here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13142 . But still none of them works!

Btw, by not working, I mean I got this error:

`undefined method`is_empty' for #:0x007f923c3c4b20>`

Basically Rails cannot find the method that I have defined inside the Reusable module that I am trying to load.

Is there any steps that I am missing? Or something problematic on Rails side?

Comment: Are you including the module in a class? Or trying to call it directly? I'm guessing the latter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is loading. If it was not, you would get an `uninitialized constant Reusable` error instead of an `undefined method` error.

If you're trying to call:

```
Reusable.is_empty(value)
```

Then `is_empty` needs to be a class method. Something like:

```
# app/lib/reusable.rb    
module Reusable

  # Check if the value is completely blank & empty
  def self.is_empty(value)
  end

end
```

Or:

```
# app/lib/reusable.rb    
module Reusable

  # Check if the value is completely blank & empty
  class << self

    def is_empty(value)
    end

  end

end
```

Depending on your preferences.

Comment: I see. Do i need to put `include Reusable` in the model/controller that I want to use? Or I do not have to do anything else since the file it's already loaded?

Comment: If you are calling it as a free-standing module, then you do not need to include it. You should be able to just `Reusable.is_empty(value)` wherever you want to.

Comment: ah cool it works! I just have one more question though, how if i would like to use `is_empty(value)` without having to put the module name in front? ( instead of `Reusable.is_empty(value)` i could just use `is_empty(value)` )

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Fires burning here and stuff. Anyways, to your question, it depends a little on where you want to do `is_empty(value)` from. But, also, there's a broader consideration about separation of responsibilities, visibility, and such. If you want to discuss, we could do a chat.

Comment: Hey no worries, sorry as well for late reply as I just saw your reply. Actually i would like to use `is_empty(value)` anywhere in the application (controller, view, model etc.). I understand that I should probably put a function like this in the helper files. But i am looking if there is a better way? And yeah, I would love if we could chat about this! :) when will you have time?

Comment: I'm around. I can set up a SO chat. Or, whatever works for you.

Comment: Cool, can you set up that SO chat please?

Comment: [Here's](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/156934/lib-files-are-not-loading-rails-5?tab=general) the link to the chat.